# Examples Realm Butterknife

Tags: android, realm, butterknife

I was wondering if anyone had any examples of using realm and butter knife together. Is it possible to use the two together?

So far what I have tried is the following, But I am not certain it is correct. I was told to use ExecuteTransaction but I'm not certain it's appropriate.

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    MainFragmentAdaptor mMainFragmentAdaptor;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    Player player;
    Realm realm;

    @BindView(R.id.et_character_name)
    EditText et_character_name;

    @OnTextChanged(R.id.et_character_name)
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text) {
        String name = text.toString();
        player.setName(name);

        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(player);
                    player.setCurrentHP(37);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("REALM SET PLAYER ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMainFragmentAdaptor);

        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    player = realm.createObject(Player.class);
                    player.setCurrentHP(37);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("REALM SET PLAYER ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (realm != null) { // guard against weird low-budget phones
            realm.close();
            realm = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use the two together?

Yes. both are independent of each other.

> I was told to use ExecuteTransaction but I'm not certain it's
>   appropriate.

You should in most cases use `executeTransaction()` since it will handle errors for you. The only reason for using `beginTransaction()` is normally if you want to have some custom error handling.*

For more information see this **[link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4217)**

Comment: Awesome, and per chance can you see anything incorrect with the code above? I i've tried running it only to have it crash on me.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: Is a link okay?
https://gist.github.com/scorchgid/23a347d136205d7506a435261fefd31d#file-logcat-butterknife-realm-L64

Comment: Please check your xml layout as your are binding view using Buttterknife for id which is not present is xml layout.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean https://gist.github.com/scorchgid/ad9b2c664624c412b0e5a8f52c7e9450

Comment: you need to show your full XML and Java code then I can help you

Comment: https://github.com/scorchgid/Avariel/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main_fragment.xml

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely fine to use `ButterKnife` and `Realm`. Both serve different purpose altogether.

***Realm***    The Realm Mobile Platform is a data layer for applications.  Like a database, data in Realms can be queried and filtered, interconnected, and persisted

***Butterknife***   Light weight library to inject views into Android components. It uses annotation processing.

As per [Christian Melchior](https://github.com/cmelchior) who is Android Tech Lead at Realm, 
`executeTransaction()` is equivalent to

```
try {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    // body of executeTransaction
    realm.commitTransaction();
} catch(Exception e) { 
    if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
         realm.cancelTransaction();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Because `executeTransaction()` it handles errors for the developer, where as `beginTransaction()` is for custom error handling if required.